# Adding return type on a function TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to declare the type of return data in a function. Here's the function:

```js
export const getCurrentUserData = async (): User => {
    const value = await storage.getItem('currentSite');
    if (value === null) {
        return '';
    } else {
        const getuserData = JSON.parse(value)
        const userData = {
            email: getuserData.userData.email,
            id: getuserData.userData.id,
            name: getuserData.userData.name,
            userKey: getuserData.userData.userKey,
            userRole: getuserData.userData.userRole,
            photo: getuserData.userData.photo,
        }
        return userData;
    }
}
```

Here's my data type:

```js
export type User = {
    email: string,
    id: string,
    name: string,
    userKey: string,
    userRole: string,
    photo: string,
}
```

Am i doing these the right way? Because it shows the error: `'Type 'User' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor '`

Comment: async function always returns a promise, so your return type should be a promise

Answer (score 1):

You need to include Promise in the signature like so:

```
export const getCurrentUserData = async (): Promise<User> => {
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
export const getCurrentUserData = async (): Promise<User> => {
const value = await storage.getItem('currentSite');
if (value === null) {
    throw new Error('Current site data not found');
} else {
    const getuserData = JSON.parse(value);
    const userData: User = {
        email: getuserData.userData.email,
        id: getuserData.userData.id,
        name: getuserData.userData.name,
        userKey: getuserData.userData.userKey,
        userRole: getuserData.userData.userRole,
        photo: getuserData.userData.photo,
    };
    return userData;
}
```

};